# How do I know dependent rpms of a a package

Tags: rpm

I want to know all the dependent rpms including recursive of a particular rpm. Is it possible?

I know that in rpm there is  an option `-R`,`--require` to now the dependency of an rpm. But I want to know even the dependency of dependent rpms.

for eg:

```
rpm -qR x.rpm

a
b
c
```

a will in turn dependent on p,q,r. How do I know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `rpmgraph`.

man rpmgraph:

```
NAME
       rpmgraph - Display RPM Package Dependency Graph

SYNOPSIS
       rpmgraph PACKAGE_FILE ...

DESCRIPTION
       rpmgraph  uses  PACKAGE_FILE  arguments  to generate a package dependency graph. 
       Each PACKAGE_FILE argument is read and added to an rpm transaction set. The 
       elements of the transaction set are partially ordered using a topological sort. 
       The partially ordered elements are then printed  to  standard output.
```

Comment: Just a note that the `rpmgraph` command is part of the Red Hat rpm-devel package. So, that package needs to be installed in order to use the rpmgraph command.

Answer (score 1):

rpm -q --whatrequires

I am wondering if this can be done , without installing package and same for build-dependencies, using zypper etc